# How does Invoking a Skill with a Specific Request work with newSession handler?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

You can read [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/supported-phrases-to-begin-a-conversation) that you can invoke a skill with a specific request.

But my skill has a handler for new sessions and as soon as I try to invoke my skill with a specific request it still ends up in this new session function.

```
const handlers = {
    'NewSession': function () {
        this.attributes.speechOutput = this.t('WELCOME_MESSAGE', this.t('SKILL_NAME'));
        this.attributes.repromptSpeech = this.t('WELCOME_REPROMT');
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes.speechOutput, this.attributes.repromptSpeech);
        },
    'RankIntent': function () {
        const rank1raw = this.event.request.intent.slots.RankOne;
        const rank2raw = this.event.request.intent.slots.RankTwo;
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the correct intent or will I have to do some if clauses in the newSession function to see what is coming in and which function should respond?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here on line 17](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-howto/blob/master/src/index.js):

> Use LaunchRequest, instead of NewSession if you want to use the
>   one-shot model Alexa, ask [my-skill-invocation-name] to (do
>   something)...

So in my approach it would be:

```
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.attributes.speechOutput = this.t('WELCOME_MESSAGE', this.t('SKILL_NAME'));
        this.attributes.repromptSpeech = this.t('WELCOME_REPROMT');
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes.speechOutput, this.attributes.repromptSpeech);
        },
    'RankIntent': function () {
        const rank1raw = this.event.request.intent.slots.RankOne;
        const rank2raw = this.event.request.intent.slots.RankTwo;
        ...
    }
}
```